# Is it possible to use two different spring-session applications with one redis server?

Tags: spring, spring-session

I´ve started using spring session successfully with one nginx, two tomcats and one redis server to implement clustered sessions and some questions have arisen.
First of all, I mean two completely applications when I talk about different applications, I don´t talk about two instances of the same application.

May I use two or more different spring-session applications to store sessions with only one redis server in production?

These applications can run in different tomcats instances?

How Spring session avoid session id conflict between different applications with one redis server?

Is it necessary to append suffix or prefix id to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Session does not natively support for scoping sessions at this time. See [gh-166](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/166) for details on tracking this.

Spring Session generates a secure random id with high level of entropy for session id's so there is extremely low probability that you will get collisions.

This means that you can use the same Redis instance for multiple applications using Spring Session so long as you are ok with the following statement:

A malicious user can use Application A's session id with Application B. Why is this important? Consider the following scenario:

- Application A is a public application which any user can create an account for.
- Application B is a private application which only users who are invited can sign up.
- The malicious user creates an account and authenticates with Application A
- The user copies their session id for Application A. They navigate to Application B and paste the session id into their cookies for Application B and are now authenticated.

This might not be a problem for you. For example, good security practice would ensure that the user is properly authorized by looking for an ADMIN role in Application B. Application A would not populate that role, so while the user is authenticated with Application B they are not authorized to use it.

Comment: I'm evaluating spring session and it rocks perfectly. I'm also migrating about thirty company applications from xml to java spring configuration. The main challenge now is spring security java configuration. We have a in-house Single SignOn solution and we integrate it with spring security. This SSO takes care of the problem you've told about malicious user you've described. Thanks for your answer @rob-winch. Sorry my typo.

Comment: Did I answer your question then? If so, can you accept the answer? If not, can you point out where I fell short?